# computed columns, how to increment a subset

Tags: sql-server

What I want to do is have a table structure like this:

```
TypeID   int       not null (foreign key)
ItemID   int       (computed value +1 for each value with same TypeId) 
Data     string
```

e.g.

```
TypeId  ItemId  Data 
1       1       "some data"
1       2       "some data"
2       1       "some data"
3       1       "some data"
3       2       "some data"
```

If I have computed columns as a key, am I going to have issues with concurrency as opposed to identity columns?

Comment: what will your formula be for this computed column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ItemId` column seems to be the result of a `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY TypeID)` (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) -- is that how you're computing it?  As such it's not really suitable as part of a key due to concurrency issues (two transactions inserting rows with the same `TypeID`, as you mention).  But what does that have to do with "how to increment a subset"?  What subset of what?  And what's your question?  Why not just make something else the key instead (typically an artificial auto-increment column)?

Comment: The above example is somewhat contrived, currently I am using identity columns (and not using the computed "ItemId" above) 
However I have a requirement from the users for a "meaningful" key to be displayed (the identity column is not appropriate).  

From what I have read on the subject I did not think that I could simply increment the ItemId for each unique TypeID (and use that as part of a primary key) - but wanted to check if there was a cunning way.

Comment: @Grayson, why does the "suitable to be displayed" column set have to be a _key_?  If the display doesn't happen smack in the middle of a transaction (which would be a mess for other reasons too!-), the pair of columns in question _will_ be unique (whether you generate `ItemId` my way, or in any other way;-).

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. I will do as you suggested.  If there was a "reasonable" way of setting up the keys as I was proposing, then (in the context of the database) I could simply things (remove a table). However, that is not a big deal... I just want to make sure I had the "best" option.

Comment: Can't get the syntax quite right on the computed column: 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition BY modelentityid ORDER BY datainstanceid DESC) I get the error: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: What clause are you using row_number in?  I'm also perplexed by the message (I've used it in a WHERE clause in the past).

Comment: I just directly put it in sql server management studio (created a new column, and put the script in the computed column section... I have been googling without much luck on this error

Answer (score 2):

I concur with Alex that your computed column could be reproduced with native analytic functionality (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK) rather than as a computed column, which likely would require using a CLR or just be better off with a trigger to populate the `itemid` column in the manner you desire.

I recommend having the `itemid` column as an identity column.  What you want sounds like a surrogate key, a fake key (not to be mixed up with natural & artificial keys) that you can use to reference & display to users without giving away underlying data modelling.  What I still don't like about the approach for your situation is that to use it, you still require two pieces of data to get a unique row/record - the typeid *and* the surrogate key.